# Qual o erro no programa?

Tags: visualg

```
Algoritmo "semnome"

Var
n1, n2,maior,menor, diferenca: real


Inicio
escreval("diferença do maior pelo menor")
escreva ("numero1 = ")
leia (n1)
escreva ("numero2 = ")
leia (n2)
se (n1>n2) entao
n1 <- maior
n2 <- menor
senao
n1 <- menor
n2 <- maior

fimse
diferenca <- (maior-menor)
escreva (diferenca)

Fimalgoritmo
```

qualquer resultado posto da zero como diferença

Comment: Não deveria ser `maior <- n1` etc?

Answer (score 1):

Como o bfavaretto comentou o erro acontece por essa inversão.

> Na sua estrutura de condicional você setou a variável `n1` e `n2` com
>   a variável `maior` e `menor` sendo que menor e maior foram declaradas
>   mais não tiveram valores atribuídos. .
>
> Tente isso:
>
> ```
> se (n1>n2) entao
>    maior <- n1
>    menor <- n2
> senao
>    maior <- n2
>    menor <- n1
> fimse
> ```

---

Fazendo o `passo a passo` no Visualg para identificar o erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde o erro acontece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Seguindo sua ideia montei um esquema:

> Código:
>
> ```
> algoritmo "semnome"
> // Função :
> // Autor :
> // Data : 28/04/2018
> // Seção de Declarações 
> var
> n1, n2, diferenca: real
>
> inicio
> // Seção de Comandos
> escreval("=============================")
> escreval("diferença do maior pelo menor")
> escreval("=============================")
> escreval("")
> escreva("Informe o 1º número: ")
> leia(n1)
> escreva("Informe o 2º número: ")
> leia(n2)
>
> limpatela
>
> se (n1 > n2) entao
>    diferenca <- (n1 - n2)
>    escreval("============================================================")
>    escreval("o número ", n1, " é maior que o número ", n2, " e a diferença é ", diferenca)
>    escreval("============================================================")
> senao
>    se (n1 < n2) entao
>       diferenca <- (n2 - n1)
>       escreval("============================================================")
>       escreval("o número ", n2, " é maior que o número ", n1, " e a diferença é ", diferenca)
>       escreval("============================================================")
>    senao
>       escreval("Os números são iguas!")
>    fimse
> fimse
> fimalgoritmo
> ```

Veja funcionando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O tutorial achei bonito, mas achei desnecessário. A resolução antes do tutorial, entretanto, não diz o que foi o problema. As imagens também não renderizaram bem. Tem textos que você colocou sobre o print do terminal que caberiam melhor no texto corrido da resposta, além de que seria mais fácil de ser lido (sim, não consegui ler os textos nos prints). Também achei que seu código de exemplo está pior arquiteto e mais repetitivo do que o original da pergunta.

Comment: A minha intenção era mostra como é possível identificar um problema usando o passo a passo do visualg. Consigo visualizar as imagem perfeitamente tanto de um smartphone como de um monitor. Quanto ao texto sobre os prints não tem nada d+ foi uma escolha minha de sinalizar. Obrigado pela critica, o importante é que autor da pergunta entenda e consiga soluciona a questão. Ao que se refere a resolução no inicio, obrigado me passei msm.